# Do I have to watch The Bourne Legacy to watch Jason Bourne?

Tags: suggested-order, the-bourne-legacy, jason-bourne

I just found out there's another Bourne Series, but it looks unoriginal. I'm going to be busy and I want to watch Jason Bourne in the cinema before I do, but I'm not sure if I can skip *The Bourne Legacy*.

Is *The Bourne Legacy* canon? Can I skip it and pretend there isn't a 4th movie? Would it continue off the 3rd movie?

Comment: They're all sorta episodic, don't you think? I mean the second one ties in with the first, but not in such a way as to detract seriously if you hadn't seen it, and both 2 & 3 had relevant flashbacks, as I recall, as needed. We're not talking films with what I would call "heavy emotional baggage" like, I dunno, Star Wars or Toy Story. ;-)

Comment: Legacy doesn't even involve the same characters... as far as I'm aware, it's filler and there's no reason to watch it if you don't really want to. Not that it's a bad film... but it's not one of the main series.

Comment: No, you dont need to watch bourne lagacy.

Comment: @Catija, there are some crossover characters, such as Landy (Joan Allen) and Hirsch (Albert Finney) , as _Legacy_ was meant to be set at the same time as _Ultimatum_, but you are correct in that it wasn't meant to be part of the main series. _Legacy_ references the previous Bourne movies, but I doubt the new one will reference _Legacy_.

Comment: I've watched the new movie, and it was awesome. Too awesome. You don't have to watch Legacy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I watched Jason Bourne in the cinema, and it continued normally off The Bourne Ultimatum exactly as a canon episode should skip the storyline of a filler.

**The Bourne Legacy is like a filler, you can skip it.** It continued after The Bourne Ultimatum, I didn't have any trouble.

**TL;DR: You can skip The Bourne Legacy and watch Jason Bourne.**