# Do I need to know Bourne's backstory before watching Jason Bourne?

Tags: jason-bourne

I'm considering going to the cinema to watch the new [Jason Bourne](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4196776/) movie. I have not seen the previous 3 movies. Is there any need to watch them before this one, or does it work as a stand-alone movie?

In other words, is there any important backstory that I should know before watching this movie?

Comment: You can skip "Legacy" for sure...

Comment: Closely related: [Do I have to watch The Bourne Legacy to watch Jason Bourne?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57466/do-i-have-to-watch-the-bourne-legacy-to-watch-jason-bourne)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, you don't need to know any backstory.

The new *Jason Bourne* film tells a more or less standalone story. It's loosely linked to the previous films - in that Bourne is a former CIA assassin who's no longer involved with the agency, while certain high-up figures within the CIA still want him 'brought in' or killed - but all the necessary information is given to you early on in the new film, so you're not left wondering what's going on or who everybody is.

**It's perfectly possible to watch and understand the new film without having watched any of the earlier films in the franchise.** But if you're still worried about being able to follow all the characters and relationships, some of whom are introduced quite fast, the following cast list taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bourne_(film)#Cast) (from which I've removed one spoiler and added one explanatory note) may help:

- [Matt Damon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Damon) as **Jason Bourne**, born David Webb, a former CIA assassin who disappeared after publicising details of the CIA's targeted assassination programs [including a program codenamed Blackbriar].
- [Tommy Lee Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Lee_Jones) as **Robert Dewey**, the current director of the CIA and leader of the Iron Hand program who holds an intention to take down Bourne after the exposure of Blackbriar.
- [Alicia Vikander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicia_Vikander) as **Heather Lee**, the head of the CIA Cyber Ops Division.
- [Vincent Cassel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_Cassel) as **the Asset**, a Blackbriar assassin working for the Iron Hand program. The Asset was captured and tortured as a result of Bourne's actions in *The Bourne Ultimatum* and harbours resentment toward him because of it.
- [Julia Stiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Stiles) as **Nicolette "Nicky" Parsons**, Bourne's former Treadstone contact in Paris whom he sent into hiding in *The Bourne Ultimatum*.
- [Riz Ahmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riz_Ahmed) as **Aaron Kalloor**, the CEO and founder of Deep Dream, a social media enterprise.
- [Ato Essandoh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ato_Essandoh) as **Craig Jeffers**, a CIA agent and Dewey's right-hand man.
- [Scott Shepherd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Shepherd_(actor)) as **Edwin Russell**, the Director of National Intelligence.
- [Bill Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Camp) as **Malcolm Smith**, a former CIA analyst who retired to the private sector.
- [Vinzenz Kiefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinzenz_Kiefer) as **Christian Dassault**, a hacker, whistleblower, and the leader of a group of privacy activists.
- [Gregg Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregg_Henry) as **Richard Webb**, Jason Bourne's father.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that whilst the new film has flashbacks into the older films, they are there to provide a bit of an insight into Bourne's past, but work as any other flashback which is made specifically for any film does.  I agree you don't need to see the others to understand.